# Django health check for urls

Tags: django, url

how can I display the health status of different urls(302,200 etc.) in an html page in my django project?

for example;
[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO6cs.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your views, you can get the status code from the `response` object.

So `context.status_code = response.status_code` And then return the template with the context as a dict.

Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/)